# почему метод не принимает JSON?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Отправляю POST запрос в метод

```
{
"login": "newUser",
"firstName": "userTwo",
"lastName": "lastUserTwo",
"eMail": "test@gmail.com",
"password": "pass1112",
"personListLink": [
    {
        "title":"tittle",
        "descrption": "desc",
        "url": "urlLink"
    }]
```

}

Через @RequestBody метод не видит его, а если через @ModelAttribute, то объект как я понял приходит пустой.

```
package ru.macakov.linkSaver.web;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import ru.macakov.linkSaver.dao.UserDao;
import ru.macakov.linkSaver.model.User;
import ru.macakov.linkSaver.services.UserService;

@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView showAll() {
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("all");
   modelAndView.addObject("users", userService.getAll());
   return modelAndView;
  }


@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showAddForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    return new ModelAndView("add_form", "user", new User());

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    userService.add(user);

    return "redirect:/LinksSaver-1.0-SNAPSHOT/";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showEditForm(@RequestParam(required = true) String login) {
    return new ModelAndView("add form", "Users", userService.get(login));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam(required = true) String login) {
    userService.remote(login);
    return "redirect:/";
}


}
```

в метод приходит

```
user = {User@6071} "Пользователь: null null"
login = null
firstName = null
lastName = null
eMail = null
password = null
personListLink = {ArrayList@6099}  size = 0
```

Ребят, подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста код текстом, а не картинками. Для редактирования вопроса воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править", расположенной под вопросом.

Comment: Изменил надеюсь так лучше

Comment: Какие у заголовки у запроса? Для отправки json должны быть `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` и `Content-Length`, после этого `@RequestBody` будет работать.

Comment: я создал класс с одим полем, все работает, видимо запрос как-то криво написал. Буду разбираться!) Добра тебе за помощь)